# Tensorboard displaying scalar without keras.fit nor estimator in TF2.0

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I have read TF 2.0 tutorial: [Using TensorBoard with other methods](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/get_started.ipynb)
Then I wrote this simple code but seems not working:

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('train_loss', dtype=tf.float32)
test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('test_loss', dtype=tf.float32)

train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs/tr')
test_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs/ts')

for ep in range(1000):
    train_loss(1*ep) # here I just want to display 1*ep...
    test_loss(2*ep) 
    tf.summary.scalar('trloss', train_loss.result(), step=ep)
    tf.summary.scalar('tsloss', test_loss.result(), step=ep)

%tensorboard --logdir logs
```

I get (in browser):

```
No scalar data was found.
Probable causes:

You haven’t written any scalar data to your event files.
TensorBoard can’t find your event files.
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by myself:

```
with train_summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('trloss', train_loss.result(), step=ep)
with test_summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('tsloss', test_loss.result(), step=ep)
```

It works! But, I couldn't find any proper documentation for this.